# How to hide Div on a certain page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide `.onsale` on my product page, to do this I have written the following code. I would like the sale badge to be hidden on my product page.

I am trying to code this so that when a product on the **shop** page is clicked on, it applies the class `.Hideonsale` to `.onsale`, therefore hiding the class on the **product** page when it opens.

**JQuery**

```
jQuery( function($) { 
$( ".product" ).on('click', function() {
  $('onsale').addClass("Hideonsale");
 });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.Hideonsale{
display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question but you are missing a `.` in your selector. `$('.onsale')`

Comment: @Turnip Thank you I just made that adjustment, however once I click on a product and get redirected to the **product** page, the '.onsale' badge shows up again

Comment: Adding or removing a class with JavaScript will not be persisted across page reloads. You need to store these changes somewhere and reload them when the page is loaded.

Comment: If these are 2 different pages then javascript doesn't communicate through different pages. Php does

Comment: @Hearner Okay that is very useful, thank you. Do you know how we would do this through php?

Comment: Sure, it's called `form` in html. This is a field that send to another .php page every field inside that `<form>`[See here a good example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: @Hearner I'm not sure what you mean? We are trying to hide a sales badge on our product page, but still want it to show on our archive shop page.